# Segment Fault (Core Dump) Error

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void stringReverse(char* s){
    char tmp;
    int i = 0;
    int j = (strlen(s)-1);
    while(i>=j){
        tmp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE* in; /* file handle for input */
    FILE* out; /* file handle for output */
    char word[256]; /* char array to store words from the input file */

   /* checks that the command line has the correct number of argument */
    if(argc !=3){
        printf("Usage: %s <input file> <output file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* opens input file for reading */
    in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(in==NULL){
        printf("Unable to read from file %s\n", argv[1]);
    }

    /* opens ouput file for writing */
    out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if(out==NULL){
        printf("Unable to read from file %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* reads words from the input file and reverses them and prints them on seperate lines to the output file */
    while(fscanf(in, " %s", word) != EOF) {
        stringReverse(word);
        fprintf(out, "%s\n", word);
    }

    /* closes input and output files */
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I keep getting a segment fault (core dump) error. What am I doing
wrong? My out file is also returned empty, which shouldn't happen.

My input is

```
abc def ghij 
klm nopq rstuv 
w xyz
```

and the output should be

```
cba 
fed 
jihg 
mlk  
qpon  
vutsr 
w  
zyx
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger?

Comment: I haven't learned how to use one in unix ;(

Comment: Then learn it now by looking it up. There's no learning C without knowing how to debug.

Comment: The common debugger on Unix/Linux is [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/). It won't be time wasted. Learn to use the spoon rather than be spoon fed.

Comment: `while(i>=j)` should be `while(i<j)`?

Answer (score 4):

Definitely you should spend some time to learn to use `gdb` and `valgrind`.
As for the code, shouldn't it be `while(i<=j)` instead of `while(i>=j)` at line 9?

**Explanation:**

The discussion between Barmar and loginn actually did a good job on explaining why the segmentation fault is happening here. The logic `while(i>=j)` is wrong but you won't get a segmentation fault for this unless you have a single character (such as 'w' in your sample input) in your input file. Why a single character input will cause segmentation fault? Because then you start your loop with i = 0 and j = 0 which satisfies the loop condition and then go onto i = 1 and j = -1 which also satisfies the incorrect loop condition. At this point an attempt to access an invalid address (`s[-1]`) will cause the segmentation fault.

If you don't have any single character in your input file then your program will simply run and print the words as they are in the output file. It won't reverse any words because the code will not enter the while loop that does the reverse because of the wrong condition. But it won't cause any segmentation fault either.

I hope I have explained it well.

Comment: That will just cause the function to return immediately, without reversing the string. It won't cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Nope, Saijb is correct and this is a valid answer. With the current code, the function exits immediatly except for a single character line in which case it just loops until `j = -1` and then segfaults

Comment: Right, didn't consider that case. It would be better if the answer explained this in detail.

Comment: @Sajib Thank you so much! My professor told me to write it as while(i>=j) but now I can see why that is wrong. I shall now spend some time learning to use gdb. Thank you again!